# Motherboard msi a68hm-e33 v2 won't boot Linux

Tags: ubuntu, boot, manjaro, hardware

I just bought a new Desktop and I did formated it's hard drive, Wich had windows 10 instaled.
I tried to boot 3 different Linux Os from 2 different Hard disks, none of them has booted. It stops in a black screen after BIOS.

1. I did a suceful installation (grub screen) of the latest Ubuntu Lts on the new desktop HD,
2. I tried to boot a live manjaro,
3. And I tried to boot an external HD with Lubuntu installed.

The BIOS boot order was correct. And I even tried to change from "legacy UEFI" to just "UEFI".

The result of all this tests were a black screen after BIOS.
It has an AMD CPU with integrated video, by the way.

Any idea of why is that happening?

Edit : BIOS images

[image: first page]

[image: Advanced settings]

[image: windows configuration]

[image: Boot settings]

Answer (score 0):

Could be a number of issues:

1. If you can't boot into a live-CD, your USB-stick might not be formatted properly.
2. Booting an OS from an external drive could not work if you installed it onto the drive using another PC.
3. Secure boot is enabled and the keys aren't enrolled.

---

You could try this, if you have another PC available:

1. Download [Ventoy](https://www.ventoy.net/en/download.html) and follow the [installation instructions](https://www.ventoy.net/en/doc_start.html) (be careful to use the proper part of the installation guide, depending on the OS you're installing it from).
2. When you are going to install Ventoy to the USB stick, you can see an 'Options' menu in the top left corner (please refer to the [screenshot](https://www.ventoy.net/static/img/ventoy2disk_en.png)), click there and enable 'GPT' and 'Secure boot'. **NB! This will erase everything on your USB!**
3. When the everything has gone well, you can download [gparted](https://downloads.sourceforge.net/gparted/gparted-live-1.4.0-5-amd64.iso) and throw it onto the USB, along with the Linux distro of your choosing.
4. On the PC you want to install Linux: enter the BIOS settings, disable 'legacy UEFI' and enable only 'UEFI'; enable 'Secure boot' and (depending on your BIOS) look for 'Windows keys' or something similar. Save the settings and exit.
5. When the PC reboots to apply the BIOS changes, boot into the USB stick you just created. It will probably tell you that the security keys have changed or something similar. Enter that you want to enroll MOK keys from the USB stick (find the selection that says 'ENROLL_MOK_KEY' or something similar) and follow the steps to enroll the keys.
6. The PC will probably reboot again and, again, boot from the USB stick. Select `gparted`. When you enter `gparted` desktop, a window will pop up with the disk management utility. From there, select the appropriate device you want are going to install the OS on and go to 'Device', click on 'Create partition table' and select 'GPT'. After the partition table has been created, format the entire disk to 'ext4' - wait for it to finish and reboot the PC.
7. Boot to USB again, and this time select the OS you are going to install and install it. As soon as it is finished, shut down the PC, remove the USB stick and power it on again.

Comment: Thanks, but I didn't found any secure boot option. I updated the post with imagens of the BIOS. And since the Ubuntu was sucefuly installed on the HD, wouldn't the problem be related to the motherboard before any pendrive problem ? Should i still do 
the steps  you recommended to me ? Help

Comment: And I just remembered that the Manjaro live pendrive is recognized and start that terminal like loading screen of gnome, so the boost starts, but after it finished, comes the black screen.

Comment: Similar, the Ubuntu HD, shows those topical intial terminal lines, as it always do when booting, before the black screen appears.

Comment: So it's like the boot process starts but it's limited to all the terminal like loading screens. And it stops before any graphical screen, like the Os logo.

Comment: Yes, there is some setting in the motherboard options that's preventing you from booting. The thing is that, if the disk was formatted to MBR instead of GPT before you enabled secure boot, the OS will *not* boot. If there is a secure boot option, it will most likely be under the 'Boot' menu (which does not seem to be the case, judging from the screenshots). Can you boot from a Live CD? If yes, open a terminal and type `parted -l`; under 'Partition table' it should tell you if it is MBR or GPT. If it is GPT and you installed the OS while 'Legacy UEFI' was enabled, you'll have to reinstall 1/2

Comment: 2/2 the OS with 'Legacy UEFI' disabled. If the partition table is MBR, you should leave the 'Legacy UEFI' option enabled. That being said, you should enable UEFI, recreate the partition table as GPT and install the OS. Please mind that if you go this route, the USB stick's partition table needs to be GPT as well, or else the install won't work. In short: Legacy UEFI + MBR = USB stick has to be MBR; if UEFI + GPT = USB stick has to be GPT.